# How to test external request with Ministest / TestCase out of controller scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mocking, minitest, stub

I'm new with Minitest particularly, at the moment everything goes ok because is not really hard to learn, but, I'm stuck with a routinary test: test a controller that upload a file to S3.

**Goal:** 
Have a test that create a new `Person.create()` object with its file, in this case is a zip with some images.

**Context:**

- I've a model `Person` with a `file` field with Paperclip and its configuration for S3.
- I've various tests files for that (in tests/models & tests/controllers of course), but, with one more test in another folder because I'm testing other class that uses the Person object to update it.

My problem is that I've tried a lot of approach searching in Google and StackOverflow but I'm not sure how to address this tests out of the Controller scope.

```
require 'test_helper'
  require 'webmock/minitest'

  class PersonPhotosUpdateTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    def setup
      # some setup here
    end

    describe "My tests" do
      test "Upload a zip file for Person" do 
        # My test here
      end
    end
  end
```

**I want in my test:**

- Create a new Person with `post :create`.
- Person should be created with the file uploaded to S3 associated.
- Assert that the file was uploaded to S3.

I suppose I need mock and/or stub for that but I'm not sure how with Minitest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to create an i[ntegration test](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing):

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'webmock/minitest'

class LocationImporterTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  before do
    stub_request(:any, "https://s3.amazonaws.com")
  end

  test "create" do
    post "/foo", { 
      # params...
    }

    assert_requested :post, "https://s3.amazonaws.com",
      :headers => {'Content-Length' => 3}, 
       :body => "abc",
      :times => 1    # ===> Success
  end
end
```

See the [webmock documents](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) for how set expectations on the HTTP request, note that Test/Unit and Minitest are interchangable.